# How to use execv() without warnings?

Tags: c++, macos, g++, warnings, execv

I am working on MacOS-X Lion with GCC 4.2. This code works, but I get a warning I would like fix:

```
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    char *args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", (char *) 0 };
    execv("/bin/ls", args);
}
```

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

I do not want the warning to be suppressed, I want not to have it at all.
It is C++ code, not C.

Using a char *const (so exactly the type required by execv()) still produces the warning.

Thank you.

Comment: This give an error, not a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be ok:

```
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    char const *args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", NULL };
    execv("/bin/ls", const_cast<char**>(args));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting a string constant to a mutable character pointer, change using an implicit cast, the compiler is warning you that newer versions of the language will not allow this cast.

When defining a string litteral c++ understands it to mean a constant character array you have defined it as a mutable character array, change your code accordingly.

Comment: awiebe: "You are converting a string constant". char *args[] is not constant.

Comment: @Pietro: No but every single one of the literals you're trying to initialise it with _are_.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
char *args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", (char *) 0 };
```

To:

```
char *const args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", NULL };
```

Comment: I keep getting the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you get the warning is that you're using g++, not gcc.
In pure C, you'd get absolutely no warnings.
It's actually quite difficult to create warning-free C++ code from this. To be honest, I tried but did not succeed.

These hurdles are one of the reasons for the existence of a certain philosophical school. See more [here](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/linus).

Comment: After reading that comment by Linus Torvalds on C++, I would like to assist to a match between Torvalds and Stroustrup. I'm sure there would be a lot of blood :-) For what I am concerned, I would never go back from std::vector to malloc!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why the accepted answer was selected, it does not remove any warnings when I run this code....

I cannot confirm on your specific platform, but adding casts to each string constant has made the warnings go away for me.

```
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    char* const args[] = {(char*)"/bin/ls", (char*)"-r", (char*)"-t", (char*)"-l", (char*) 0 };
    execv("/bin/ls", args);
}
```

OR

```
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    char *args[] = {(char*)"/bin/ls", (char*)"-r", (char*)"-t", (char*)"-l", (char*) 0 };
    execv("/bin/ls", args);
}
```

It may be overly verbose and annoying, but the warnings go away.

I'm running this on: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Comment: The important difference is `char const*` vs `char * const`! First one is a pointer to *constant char*, second is a *constant pointer* to char. See also [Constness](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Constness)

Answer (score 0):

change

`char *args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", "-l", (char *) 0 };`

to

`char args[] = {(char*)"/bin/ls", (char*)"-r", (char*)"-t", (char*)"-l", 0 };`

for usability u may will make a simple convert method.

Comment: You mean I should define an array of 8 bit chars an put 64 bit pointers inside?