# start terminal (sh) from execv return error : /bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file

Tags: c, linux, bash, operating-system, embedded-linux

i am trying to perform the command sh that start a new terminal in Linux from  a c program, but i get this error  /bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file when i am using execv ()and same result with fork and then execv.
 but when i tried it system command a succeed , how can i do this command with execv?

work's :

```
int main (){
        system("sh");
        return 0;
}
```

does'nt work :

```
int main (){

        int ret=0;
        char *argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "/bin/sh",NULL};
        ret=execv(argv[0], argv);

        printf("ret: %d \n",ret);
        return 0;
}
```

this code return this error :
/bin/sh: /bin/sh: cannot execute binary file

Comment: try: ```"/bin/bash","-c","/bin/sh"```

Comment: same error when i try this :                                                                 
 `    int main (){

        int ret=0;
        char *argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "/bin/bash","-c","/bin/sh",NULL};
        ret=execv(argv[0], argv);
        return 0;
}  `

Comment: you doubled ```/bin/bash```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use execv() without warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10790719/608639), [How to use execv system call in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32142164/608639), etc.

Comment: The reason the original is failing is because it's the equivalent of running the command `/bin/bash /bin/sh`, and if you run that at the command line you'll get the exact same error. The reason is that by default, /bin/bash interprets its first argument *as a shell script file* to be executed, and /bin/sh is not a shell script, it's a binary.

Comment: All the `exec...()` functions ONLY return IF they fail.  so the only statements to follow a call to one of those functions (no need to put it in a `if()` statement) are: `perror( "exec...() failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat aa.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main (){

        int ret=0;
        char *argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c","/bin/sh",'\0'};
        ret=execv(argv[0], argv);

        printf("ret: %d \n",ret);
        return 0;
}

gcc aa.c -o aa

./aa 
sh-4.4$
```

and... what about just:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main (){

    int ret=0;
    char *argv[] = {"/bin/sh",'\0'};
    ret=execv(argv[0], argv);

    printf("ret: %d \n",ret);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this answer is still wrong about how to handle a call to `execv()'

Comment: regarding: `return 0;`  in general, returning 0 indicates success. But the code was not successful.  Suggest: `return -1;` to properly indicate the failure